# Google Maps not scrolling

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I have a homepage which contains a listview and one of the children is a googlemap. The problem is that when I want to navigate in maps, I want to scroll in maps to find some place, listview controller gets triggered and the listview gets scrolled.
if I want to scroll horizontally its not a problem, but when I want to scroll vertically listview gets scrolled instead. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GoogleMap(
   cameraTargetBounds: CameraTargetBounds.unbounded,
  initialCameraPosition: _initialPosition,
  onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
  tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
  scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
  gestureRecognizers:                          
    <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>[
    new Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
    () => new EagerGestureRecognizer(),
                                ),
                              ].toSet(),
     zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
     polylines: _polylines)
```

**Add these parameters in your Google Map widget**

```
scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
      gestureRecognizers:                          
        <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>[
        new Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
        () => new EagerGestureRecognizer(),
               ),
              ].toSet(),
```